# BlogEngine Image Upload

Tags: asp.net, blogengine.net

I cannot upload an image - broken image gif appears. The markup generated is:

```
<img style="float: left;" src="/mysite/IMAGES/2012/10/myimage.jpg.jpgx" alt="" />
```

I see no such folder in the project. What is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem fixed itself when I upgraded Web site project from BlogEngine 2.6 to 2.7